# Greek letters appearing lower in equations

Tags: fonts

I have noticed that my equations containing Greek letters, especially `\chi` looks like letter chi is somehow 'down'. For instance

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=DarkOrchid, citecolor=ForestGreen, linkcolor=MidnightBlue, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}    

$\chi_{\left[\mu\right.}\nabla_\nu \chi_{\left.\sigma\right]}=0$

\end{document}
```

Gives this

[image]

Why is that, and could that be fixed? I mean, if you look at nabla and chi, they are clearly not aligned on the bottom. In fact now that I look at it, it seems that `\nabla` is the one that's not aligned good :
EDIT: The answer by egreg works :)

Comment: I'll try that, but your answer was wrong, since I don't want the `\chi` inside the parenthesis (small). This parenthesis needs to be with the indexes only (`\mu`, `\nu`, `\sigma`) since it denotes the anti-symmetrization of the indices in general relativity. `\nabla` and `\chi` needs to be the same height, while square parenthesis and indices needs to be smaller, and as subscripts...

Comment: yes, I realized that too late :-) I have deleted my answer, using the `\rchi` command defined in egreg answer works fine

Comment: All is good, plus that answer you posted did the trick :) Thanks :)